# When hovering/viewing Javascript Documentation in IntelliJ, what are all of the extra symbols?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea

So I'm trying out IntelliJ and possibly moving away from Eclipse.  I see I can hover over Javascript methods and actually see some info, which is great.  But how do I find out more about what is being shown to me?  In the pic below, what does the "?" mean?  Does 'void' mean there is not a 'return' statement?

Is this JSDoc?  This is old legacy code, so I know there is not any commenting above the function to give more info, so I'd like to know what's going on here.  Is this just IntelliJ extrapolating the function arguments and creating its own interpretation?

I assume there's a guide or legend out there for this.  But after searching around for a while I feel like I don't know the right search term to look for.  Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: We don't use TypeScript at all in our current app.

[image: pic]

Comment: Personally I don't recommend using those heavy IDEs for JavaScript. They're clunky for the lightweight work JS does -- that being said, perhaps it's trying to doc Java code instead?

Comment: @SterlingArcher No, it's definitely JS code from a JS function in another file.

Comment: Looks like the function's signature is in Typescript, `?` means optional and in Typescript you can specify types (which can be inferred from the name) and `void` does mean no return value.

Answer (score 0):

Quick documentation is mostly based on comments in code. In this case the information comes from bundled definition files (In this case, a `d.ts` file which is a TypeScript type defintion file). For the methods defined in the project or in its dependencies, IDEA shows information from the JSDoc comments attached to functions.

Looks as if the function is defined in a `d.ts` file, because explicit type declarations are used, so `?` indicates optional parameter, and `void` means that the function is not returning a value.

Comment: We don't have any typescript in our app currently, so that's why I'm wondering where this stuff comes from.  Must be IDEA making it's best guess.  I'm curious how it decides if a parameter is optional or not if it's not explicitly stated.

Comment: Well in javascript you don't have to pass the arguments and the function would still run, typescript would throw an error so it might be based on that.